# Inverse Laplace transform of convolution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, dirac-delta

$$\int_{0}^t \sin(2\pi(t-T)) \delta(t-5) \, dt$$

Wouldn't you just replace the $T$ in $\sin(2\pi(t-T))$ with a $5$ and that would be the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the delta function is involved in the integrand the integral is not necessarily of the convolution type. This is seen by:
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{t} \sin(2\pi(t-T)) \, \delta(t-5) \, dt \\
&= \begin{cases} \sin(2\pi(5-T)) & t>5 \\ 0 & t<5 \end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases} - \sin(2\pi \, T)) & t>5 \\ 0 & t<5 \end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Integration variable and integration limit shouldn't be the same variable.